# Compatibility of renormalisation with the quantum-classical correspondence principle

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, classical-field-theory, semiclassical

We know that Quantum Theories obey the Heisenberg equations of the motion, taking the expected values of which gives us the classical equations.

Also, We replace the mass and coupling parameters of a Quantum Theory with limits like $\displaystyle\lim _{\Lambda \rightarrow 0} m(\Lambda) $. These limits are infinite quantities,  but plugging them into the probability calculations gives us finite predictions. This recipe is part of the definition of the Quantum Theory.

What I'm worried about is that the parameters of coupled classical fields are just normal finite numbers,  instead of limits. We do use infinite masses, but only in the case of field-point particle interaction theories. We don't use infinite parameters for coupled classical fields.

**Then how would the correspondence principle still hold if the quantum and the classical theories have different parameters?**

Comment: I'm not sure a principle like that ever held.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Quantum Mechanics reproduces classical mechanics in a limit. This is the well known [correspondence principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle#:~:text=In%20physics%2C%20the%20correspondence%20principle,limit%20of%20large%20quantum%20numbers.) .  To derive this fact, we can either use the fact that the path integral favors the classical path in the high energy limit, or we can also use Ehrenfest's theorem and we can assume sharply peaked Gaussian wavefunctions to bypass the uncertainty principle. But both these methods require the parameters to be the same.

Comment: @ConnorBehan The correspondence principle is known to hold in non relativistic QM. It must also hold in QFT as we know that classical electrodynamics produces correct predictions. So QFT must reproduce it.

Comment: You're aware that QED strictly speaking doesn't exist right? I'm worried that after bypassing all technicalities like this you'll be back to just $0+1d$ QM and free QFT.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Do you think my answer is on the right track?

Comment: I like the idea of taking the classical limit of a lattice QFT. But it sounds like it would be easier to understand the renormalization aspect in an example without spinors first.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Why does QED not exist? Isn't the Landau pole only speculative, given that we don't have very large orders of perturbation theory?

Comment: Ok, I should've said it's still not known. But do you really think every Lagrangian which gives well defined classical EOMs also gives a well defined QFT?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is no incompatibility. As Connor Behan's comment says, QED does not really exist in the ultraviolet. So to make sense of this question, we first have to work with a QED that is well-defined : Lattice QED.

Now, in lattice QED, our parameters won't be infinite but will just be very large depending on the lattice size. On this theory, we can take a classical limit to obtain a lattice classical electrodynamics theory with very large parameters. It seems like there is some incompatibility here because the classical electrodynamics that produces correct predictions in our daily lives does not have extremely large parameters.

**But** we have to remember that the classical field theory that the correspondence principle yielded is a theory of a **spinor field** coupled to the electromagnetic field. This isn't the classical electrodynamics that we're familiar with as we don't model the classical electrons as a spinor field.

To model an electron from Newtonian mechanics, we have to take **another limit** on the spinor-electromagnetic interaction theory that the correspondence principle yielded us. In this limit, we approximate the current density of the spinor field with an sharply peaked **delta-like function**.

After taking this limit, we end up with a theory of the electromagnetic coupled to **almost point-like particle** of extremely large negative mass. This theory reproduces the classical electrodynamics that we're amiliar with, as we know that we have to model point-like particles in classical electrodynamics with an extremely large negative mass.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by QED not existing in the UV? If you're referring to a potential Landau pole, I think the jury is out on that until we have large order perturbative calculations; even $\phi^4$ theory might not suffer from a Landau pole.

Comment: @user196574 I was talking about the Landau pole, yes.